# User Registration

Tags: 7, users

I am using drupal 7.I have enabled email verification for new user registration.However the mail is not being sent for new user registration.
The site is hosted on a webserver and not running on localhost.Need help to resolve this issue as the site is ready to be Up and Running .

Comment: Are you on shared hosting?  Have you tested whether you are able to send mail from the server outside of Drupal?

Comment: Sorry for reply after a long gap.its not shared hosting.

Comment: create a php file that uses the php mail() function to email you and report back with what happens.

Comment: Yes, looks like the server may be not properly configured to send e-mails. Check the spam folder too.

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to get email of welcome messge with drupal 7?](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/45760/how-to-get-email-of-welcome-messge-with-drupal-7)