# how to get email of welcome messge with drupal 7?

Tags: users

After creating new account with Drupal 7 I am getting the message.

> Thank you for applying for an account. Your account is currently
>   pending approval by the site administrator.In the meantime, a welcome
>   message with further instructions has been sent to your e-mail
>   address.

But when I check my email account I am not getting that welcome email.

Comment: are you running your site on localhost? how did you configure your SMTP settings?

Comment: Its running on cloud server ,On server side I checked email configuration Its working server ,I think I need check Drupal environment setting for email and i don't know how to check it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Follow below steps to solve problem !

- Check your server smtp log or mail log
- Check your spam folders in mail box.
- Make sure smtp or mail server are up & running in your hosting server or local server.
- Check drupal recent log entries for any errors related to same !

Comment: Not showing anything about email registration message..

Comment: Ok.. got ans ,I checked at mail server  i wasn't start ,now its running .and I am able to send  email ..Thanks for guidance.